# What's the difference between magit-branch-checkout and magit-branch-and-checkout?

Tags: magit

If I'm on the commandline, and I'm in the master branch, and I want to create a new branch and immediately start working on it, I'd just do `git checkout -b foo`.

So I'm looking for the magit equivalent to this, i.e., I'd like to be able to call some magit function from within a branch, and then find myself working on the same buffer, but in a new branch that I've named.  Once I find that function, I intend to bind it to a key so that I can avoid having to muck around with transient states and such.

In the [magit docs](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Branch-Commands.html), I see two different commands that might qualify:

1. `magit-branch-and-checkout` which, according to the manual, "creates a new branch like `magit-branch`, but then also checks it out."  (Incidentally, this is kind of a bizarre bit of documentation, since according to the very same page of the manual, `magit-branch` does not, in fact, create a new branch, but rather is a prefix command that puts one in a branching transient stage.  so... huh??)
2. `magit-branch-checkout` which, according to the docs, takes the name of a branch from the user (I assume `magit-branch-and-checkout` must do that too, right?  unless, like, magit just picks a name for you for the new branch?), and then, per the docs, "If the user enters a new branch name, then it creates and checks that out, after also reading the starting-point from the user."

So, those sound like *the exact same functionality.*  Except maybe that `magit-branch-checkout` asks for a "starting point" (is that a commit hash?  a preexisting branch?  we are not told.).  But if that's the difference between the two, then this raises a sub-puzzle, viz.: how does magit determine the starting point for whatever `magit-branch-and-checkout` does?

So if I wanted to just do the magit equivalent of `git checkout -b foo` and immediately be working on the buffer in the new branch, would I use one of those?  Something else entirely?  Impossible within magit?

(I really wish there were a translation table somewhere from ordinary commandline git calls to magit function calls.)

Comment: The "starting point" is any git commit reference, which might be a commit hash, a branch name, a tag, a symbolic reference... anything which git accepts as a point in the commit history.

Comment: I think all of your confusion is due to a typo in the docs.  I believe "creates a new branch like magit-branch" should read "creates a new branch like magit-branch-create".

Comment: I just updated that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think all of your confusion is due to a typo in the docs. I believe "creates a new branch like magit-branch" should read "creates a new branch like magit-branch-create".

So <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> `magit-branch-and-checkout` does this:

> Create [and checkout] a new branch. The user is asked for a branch or arbitrary revision to use as the starting point of the new branch. When a branch name is provided, then that becomes the upstream branch of the new branch. The name of the new branch is also read in the minibuffer.

While <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> `magit-branch-checkout` does this:

> This command checks out an existing or new local branch. It reads a branch name from the user offering all local branches and a subset of remote branches as candidates. Remote branches for which a local branch by the same name exists are omitted from the list of candidates. The user can also enter a completely new branch name.
>
> - If the user selects an existing local branch, then that is checked out.
> - If the user selects a remote branch, then it creates and checks out a new local branch with the same name, and configures the selected remote branch as the push target.
> - If the user enters a new branch name, then it creates and checks that out, after also reading the starting-point from the user.
>
> In the latter two cases the upstream is also set. Whether it is set to the chosen starting point or something else depends on the value of magit-branch-adjust-remote-upstream-alist.

---

So to answer your questions:

> magit-branch-checkout asks for a "starting point" (is that a commit hash? a preexisting branch? we are not told.)

A "starting point" means the same thing as `<start-point>` does in Git's own documentation (see, e.g., `man git-branch`): any commit reference -- which might be a commit hash, a branch name, or a tag (i.e. anything which git accepts as a point in the commit history).

> how does magit determine the starting point for whatever `magit-branch-and-checkout` does?

Magit acts contextually -- in most cases where a reference is read from the user, the reference at point will be offered as a default value.  If there is no commit at point, then a default value may be offered (in this case, the current HEAD commit).

So a great deal of the time you would just type <kbd>RET</kbd> at that prompt to use the default.  So long as you understand where the default value is coming from, the simplest way of selecting a commit to do something with is usually to arrange that it will be the default value (typically by having point on the relevant line).

> So if I wanted to just do the magit equivalent of `git checkout -b foo` and immediately be working on the buffer in the new branch, would I use one of those?

You *could* use either -- it will only really affect the order in which you enter the two arguments (being the name of the new branch, and its starting point).  I always use <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> for this.